# ReactJS / WP Picard theme error

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wp-api

Hi I am currently learning and experimenting with the ReactJS / WP theme by Jack Lenox

```
https://github.com/Automattic/Picard
```

I when I have installed it is not displaying the posts & the Console is displaying this message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of null
```

Anyone help? Thanks heaps :)

Comment: I have also tried installing WP API v1 and v2 (beta4 and beta5) of the plugin & still no luck. When I install v2 is gives me the error. Fatal error: Class 'WP_JSON_Comments' not found in .../functions.php line 163

Answer (score 0):

I solved 'Fatal error: Class 'WP_JSON_Comments' not found in .../functions.php line 163' this error by downloading wp-rest plugin from wordpress plugin center, current Version is 1.2.4.https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Current picard is using wp-rest V1, wp-rest v2 still in beta. refer to: https://github.com/Automattic/Picard/issues/43

Also I updated my wordpress to 4.4.1

Comment: Don't ask question in answer section. Post a new question with your problem.

Comment: hey @the_UB, it wasn't a question! i was showing the solution! Please read the answer more specific next time!